# Matlab Aspect Ratio Issue

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, aspect-ratio

Recently, I've been using matlab to run a particle aggregation simulation, and I use its plotting itnerface to represent each particle.  Thus, I've put together some code which adjusts the size of a marker such that it is equivalent to the actual particle's diameter - in relation to the window's aspect ratio and such.  Well, this works very well if I'm dealing with a square domain; see below.

[image]

As you can see, the markers are sized such that particles will settle out on topof each other perfectly.  Here's the plotting code for that image:

```
%%Initial Plot at time t = 0 Along with Scaling in the Y-Direction
figure;    h=scatter(Pos(1,:),Pos(2,:),6,jet(length(Pos(1,:))),'filled','MarkerEdgeColor','k','linewidth',1);
hold on
axis equal
axis ([0 dp 0 dp]*L*Scale)
currentunits = get(gca,'Units');
set(gca, 'Units', 'Points');
axpos = get(gca,'Position');
set(gca, 'Units', currentunits);
markerWidth = dp/diff(ylim)*axpos(4); % Calculate Marker width in points
set(h, 'SizeData', markerWidth^2)
```

Well, I added in periodic boundary conditions to my simulation, and this means that I can have 3X the window size shown above without much additional computation cost.  So, I wanted to plot up a 3x1 domain (x is basically 3X longer than the y dimension of the domain).  However, I'm having troubling sizing the particles appropriately such that they will be scaled properly in the y-direction yet also touch along the x-direction.  I think I could do this using some kind of aspect ratio code, but I can't get it to work.  Any ideas?  Here's the code/result I came up with:

```
%Plot all of the data
figure;
h=scatter(Pos(1,:),Pos(2,:),6,jet(length(Pos(1,:))),'filled','MarkerEdgeColor','k','linewidth',1);
hold on
axis equal
axis ([0 3*dp 0 3*dp]*L*Scale)
currentunits = get(gca,'Units');
set(gca, 'Units', 'Points');
axpos = get(gca,'Position');
set(gca, 'Units', currentunits);
markerWidth = dp/diff(ylim)*axpos(4); % Calculate Marker width in points
set(h, 'SizeData', (markerWidth)^2)
axis ([0 3*dp 0 dp]*L*Scale)
```

It produces the following result,which is obviously incorrect :(...
[image]

Comment: Oh! A high-quality question. Haven't seen one in a while on that tag.

Comment: I giggled I admit...

Comment: Thought about drawing the circles by yourself instead of using scatter? I think it's more appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like

```
%cirlce def
circx = sin(linspace(0,2*pi,100));
circy = cos(linspace(0,2*pi,100));

%example data
[mgx mgy] = meshgrid(5:5:100, 5:5:100);
x = reshape(mgx,[],1); %circles centers x
y = reshape(mgy,[],1); %circles centers x
r = 2.5*rand(400,1);   %radii
c = 250*rand(400,1);   %colors

% draw
figure
hold on
for i=1:numel(x)
  fill(r(i)*circx+x(i), r(i)*circy+y(i), c(i))
end
```

so that all all geometric data is fixed into coordinate axes space. 
Example output is:

[image: Example result]

Comment: Hmmmm, very very interesting repsonse, but I'm not sure if this will work  with what I'm doing; I'll do some testing and comment.  Regardless, thank you very much for the detailed repsonse.  I was hoping to make the scatter function work with what I was doing somehow though.  Here's a thought: would I possibly be able to extend the x-axis once the marker sizes are set in the y-direction without modifying aspect ratio?

Comment: I don't see why this shouldnt work. Just define the axis ranges with xlim and ylim and set `axis equal`. As opposed to the scatter solution the definition of "my" circles are completely bound to real coordinates and not only to a centerpoint and a "look and feel" type of "size".